# What's a German word for »Sandbagger«?

Tags: english-to-german, single-word-request

A [sandbagger](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sandbagger) is someone who

> One who [sandbags](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sandbag) (misleads about his/her ability level in order to win [bets](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bet))

And [sandbagging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbagging) means

> hiding the strength, skill or difficulty of something or someone early in an engagement

with examples from different sports like grappling, racing and poker. The [German wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbagging) also has an entry saying it derives from boxing and is also used to refer to chess players deliberately keeping a low rating.

I don't know any good German equivalent of *sandbagger*, though.

- Langenscheidt has no useful entries for either [sandbagger](https://de.langenscheidt.com/englisch-deutsch/sandbagger) ("Segelboot mit Sandsäcken als Ballast" or "Verbrecher, der jemanden mit einem Sandsack niederschlägt") or [sandbagging](https://de.langenscheidt.com/englisch-deutsch/search?term=sandbagging&q_cat=%2Fenglisch-deutsch%2F) (redirects to *sandbag*).
- It's mentioned in a discussion on [LEO](https://dict.leo.org/forum/viewUnsolvedquery.php?idThread=140587&idForum=1&lang=de&lp=ende) about a *Tiefstapler*, but the description of *Tiefstapler* doesn't fit: "Er ist ein angenehmer Tiefstapler, trotz seiner Expertise stellt er die nicht so zur Schau oder gibt an."
- PONS doesn't even know *sandbagger*, but has an interesting [entry](https://en.pons.com/translate?q=sandbagging&l=deen&in=en&lf=en&qnac=) on *sandbagging*: "Sich zurückhalten"
- I looked up *Tiefstapler* in the [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Tiefstapelei) ("Untertreibung; Abschwächung, [falsche] Bescheidenheit, Herabspielen, Understatement, Unterbewertung, [vornehme] Zurückhaltung, Zurücknahme") and the [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Tiefstapelei) and found *die Tiefstapelei*. I miss the aspect of hustling a bit (while hustler is too broad).

**Is there a German equivalent of *sandbagger* - someone who makes themselves appear weaker to fool their competitors?**

Comment: Interestingly enough, Sandbagger is German for sand excavator

Comment: *Tiefstapler* is the correct term, it's built analog to *Hochstapler* and conveys the same meaning.

Comment: The description in LEO is not a good one, because *Tiefstapler* does not fit *angenehm* - if one considers the other person's pudency pleasant, the would rather call that person *bescheiden*.

Comment: @infinitezero: Absolutely, and when reading the term "Sandbagger" (in this question or elsewhere), I would definitely assume this refers to a children's toy for use in a sandbox (or at the beach).

Comment: Only Janka seems to have it right

Comment: "Sandbagger" goes back to stockcar racing.  You'd hide sandbags (loaded with sand) in your car while running the trials.  This slows you down to a certain extent, and gets you a better place in the starting lineup.  For the race itself, you remove the sandbags - better acceleration and higher speed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Der Tiefstapler** is built as an analogon to *der Hochstapler*.

- *Der Hochstapler* is someone **who deceives people** e.g. by faking knowledge, wealth or contacts. *Die Hochstapelei* is the whole setup of smoke and mirrors.
  It's *hoch* + *stapeln* == *stack high*, about building a stack of abilities higher than one would expect so it seems to be a good opportunity to start a business with this person.
  Note *hochstapeln* is mostly about business and jobs. There are distinct words for people who just brag (*Angeber*) and people who fake a love interest (*Heiratsschwindler*).

*Der Tiefstapler* also deceives people, but not by stacking high but instead by stacking low. That's the whole idea behind this word formation.

> Ich verstehe nicht viel davon. – Du elender Tiefstapler hast ein Buch darüber geschrieben!

In contrary to *der Hochstapler*, *der Tiefstapler* isn't about serious business but about social interaction. What makes it a bit complicated is a certain grade of modesty is the default way of ranking your own abilities in interaction between Germans, Austrians, Swiss Germans. That's why *Duden* gives *falsche Bescheidenheit* as an explanation.

So, *die Tiefstapelei* is a really **gross** kind of understatement, so extreme it cannot be tolerated silently.

Comment: How does *Tiefstapler* fit to "makes themselves appear weaker to fool their competitors"? As far as I understand your answer, the Tiefstapler has no intention to fool any competitor or to beat them while they thought to be on winner's side. Given example has no "cannot be tolerated silently" or forces the Tiefstapler to change his behavior because the others would have a disadvantage if he keeps doing so. It simply says the second speaker knows and claims that first speaker should speak out his opinion.

Comment: It's a book about golf, no?

Comment: Hochstapler hat auch eine völlig andere Bedeutung: Fork lift truck. Wird im Warenhaus benutzt um Paletten hochzustapeln.

Comment: A "Tiefstapler" is guilty of "hiding his light under a bushel" rather than guilty of  "cheating" as the word "sandbagger" implies.

Comment: @Janka: no, I see no limitation or at least a connection to golf or a book mentioned in the question. I had no idea "tiefstapeln" could have a different meaning in Golfing than in general.

Comment: @JRE: In golf, you are announcing your handicap before play. A draw is when both golfers reach par plus their own handicap. If you announce your handicap higher than real, you are going to win the game. You are a sandbagger.

Comment: @Janka:  As may be.  I don't play golf, and hadn't seen any reference to "Tiefstapler" having any special meaning to golf players in this thread.

Comment: Here's something interesting from Douglas Edwards' [Google-Mitarbeiter 59](https://books.google.de/books?id=s6Ta_IYBAR8C&lpg=PT224&ots=2PPYUncy7F&dq=tiefstapler%20golf&hl=de&pg=PT224#v=onepage&q=tiefstapler%20golf&f=false): "Drei Monate später hatten Omid und sein Team ihr Ziel wieder übertroffen. Beim dritten Mal fingen wir an, Omid einen »Sandbagger« (Tiefstapler beim Golf) zu nennen."

Answer (score 9):

Regarding the aspect "appear [weaker] to fool" I would say it is simply a [Täuschung](https://www.dwds.de/wb/T%C3%A4uschung) / [Täuschungsmanöver](https://www.dwds.de/wb/T%C3%A4uschungsman%C3%B6ver).

That is not specific to "appear *weaker*", it is just to appear as someone else to make a different impression than you would if you show your true being.

As you read about *Tiefstapler/ Tiefstapelei* it is more a "polite behavior", like you don't talk about your abilities, you just show them once they are needed.

Answer (score 4):

In games, in particular in card games with a bidding phase such as skat, this behaviour is called "mauern". Note that this meaning of "mauern" is more or less restricted to gaming, though.

Comment: "mauern" may be the best translation available, but it's still not quite fitting - it means playing unnecessarily *defensively* rather than *weakly*. A good defense in e.g.soccer can require supreme skill.

Comment: @KilianFoth It's not "*playing weakly*", but it's "pretending to have a *weak hand*", or more precisely, "not bidding (enough) in spite of having a strong hand".

Answer (score 4):

The most similar I can think of is

> [Bluffer](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Bluffer) (*compare* [bluffen](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/bluffen), [Bluff](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Bluff))

Related: [Simulant](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Simulant), [Heuchler](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Heuchler)

Comment: true, `bluffen` is much more gaming specific than my broad `täuschen`

Comment: Ein Bluff ist das _Voräuschen einer nicht vorhandenen Stärke_. Hier geht es aber um das _Verschleiern einer vorhandenen Stärke_, also genau um das Gegenteil. Daher gebe ich hier -1.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: Ein Bluffer will etwas erreichen, je nach Zweckmäßigkeit stellt er sich stark oder schwach; _»bluffen«_ heißt täuschen.

Comment: Das ist in meinen Augen halt wirklich falsch. Ein Bluff ist immer das Vortäuschen einer zu stärkeren Hand. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluff_(poker), https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluff Vgl. auch die Etymologie von https://www.dwds.de/wb/Bluff Aber vielleicht hat sich der Begriff gewandelt, und ich habe es nicht mitbekommen. Der Duden hat die allgemeine, in meinen Augen ungenaue Definition als bloße "Täuschung". Kannst du mir vielleicht Beispiele der Verwendung von _Bluff_ nennen, in denen damit eine vorgetäuschte Schwäche bezeichnet wird?

Comment: Im Englischen jedenfalls scheint es diese Bedeutungserweiterung nicht zu geben: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bluff Das heißt natürlich nicht, dass sich das Deutsche Wort _Bluff_ nicht eigenständig weiterentwickelt haben könnte. Aber ohne eine relevante Anzahl von Beispielen fällt es mir schwer, das zu glauben.

Comment: OK. Ich hab mal stichprobenartig Spiegel Online nach _Bluff_ durchsucht (https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3A+spon.de+Bluff), und man findet tatsächlich die allgemeine Verwendung. Ich war also zu vorschnell in meiner Bewertung. Tut mir leid. Wenn du einen minor Edit machst, nehme ich sie zurück.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: Wenn ein Bettler sich ärmer darstellt als er ist. _»Der blufft doch!«_

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is a fitting German word, but there is an idiom

> mit angezogener Handbremse spielen
>
> mit angezogener Handbremse fahren
>
> etwas mit angezogener Handbremse machen

meaning you aren't doing something the best you can in order to save your energy or because you don't have to.

So you could paraphrase a sandbagger as

> Jemanden der (absichtlich) mit angezogener Handbremse spielt (um seine Gegner in Sicherheit zu wiegen)

---

And to add a few words to your list

> Abzocker
>
> Trickser
>
> Trickspieler

You may even think about the english word

> Hustler

as some movies and TV-series already introduced this word and it's meaning to some Germans.

Answer (score 2):

Langenscheidts Slang-Wörterbuch has only the verb *to sandbag* and gives the translation:

> täuschen, über den Tisch ziehen

Unfortunately *Täuscher* is far too general (and Looking dated) and there is no snappy substantive for *über den Tisch ziehen*.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely pejorative term to be used in this context is "Abzocker" even though it does not imply the particular way in which someone is getting better odds than the other party is aware of.  Another is "Schauspieler" in a derogative manner, like "Was falle ich Depp auch auf so einen Schauspieler herein?!".

Comment: Ich dachte einfach an „Zocker“.